# Any recommendations for a multilingual feature/addon with RTL and LTR languages on EE4?

Tags: multi-language, ee4, multilingual

Is there a native functionality for additional languages in EE4 or should we go for an addon for a site with LTR and RTL languages?

Please share your experiences.

Comment: I wish EE would give ML as a native feature. Unfortunately it is not. You have to use Publisher module. (That is not cheap at all)

Comment: Was expecting ML as native feature. Craft has something like that native. It's a shame.

Comment: Craft has many more features in native.. Image manipulations like ce_image, Powerful Search like low search, Pages management Like Structure, Caches like Ce_cache, ML like Transcribe, Route definition from backend, Matrix > Supertable > Matrix loop and much more.

Comment: Unfortunately EE don't have such features as native. But developers of mentioned plugin work really hard to add those great features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay it seems you are into this too.
if you want to spend 200$ use https://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher-2

if not; here is the tips for an easy way to do it.
lets say that you have two languages
English - en
Arabic - ar

first duplicate your fields in your channels and make sure that you suffix the field name with the short-code of your language Like:

{title_ar}
{body_en}
{body_ar}

if you need categories add a custom field for your categories lets say the English is your default language :
{category_name_ar}

if you have variable; you can use the suffix too, like:
{home_en} : home
{home_ar} : الرئيسية

=== in you blog template ===
use the template routs and make sure the segment_1 as the language short-code like:
template group Blog/index

```
/{lang:regex[(en|ar)]}/blog/{section:category}/{page:pagination}
```

now the url of the "Blog" will be like:
https://localhost/ar/blog/
https://localhost/en/blog/

in your template the code will be like this:

```
   <ul>
      <li>{home_{segment:lang}}</li>
    {!-- this will translate the variable upon requested URL --}
    </ul>



 {exp:channel:categories}
        <a href="{path='{segment:lang}/blog/'}">
    {if segment_1 == "ar"}
{category_name_ar}
{if:else}
{category_name}
{/if}
    </a>
    {/exp:channel:categories}

    {exp:channel:entries channel="blog" }
<h2> 
  {if segment_1 == "ar"}
    {title_ar}
    {if:else}
    {title}
    {/if}
</h2>

<p>{body_{segment:lang}}</p>
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

there is many ways to do so 
this is the easiest way to do it natively

hope you find this useful

Comment: I’ve followed the same principle for many sites now but with a global_variable. Template code is then without if / ifelse conditionals. There is a article here http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-language-solutions-for-expressionengine/

Comment: GREAT I know it, it is better to work with http://republiclabs.com/expressionengine/republic-variables, in the past EE4 seems fadeout,
developers are running away. no more porting one company is Monopoly add-ons.
I am shifting to Craft